# Function of a function using SphericalPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, graphics3d, procedural-programming

If anyone has any idea how to turn all of that plotting stuff (`hcpii4plot`) into a function which takes `hcpii4angfunc[θ, ϕ]` as an argument, that would make my notebook a lot neater and easier to read. I have been struggling with this for a couple of months now and couldn't find how to do it anywhere online...

```
hcpii4angfunc[θ_, ϕ_] = -1.1619488688971678` + 
  0.8938068222285906` Cos[2 θ] + 
  3.1283238778000673` Cos[2 θ]^2

hcpii4plot = 
  SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, 
   ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ, r}, 
     ColorData["DarkRainbow"][hcpii4angfunc[θ, ϕ]]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> False, Boxed -> False, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1.3, 1.3}, {-1.3, 1.3}, {-1.22, 1.22}}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 14], Ticks -> None, 
   AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{-0.05, 0.05}], 
   Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}, ViewPoint -> {-2, -2, 1}, 
   ViewVertical -> {1, 1, 1}];
Graphics[Inset[hcpii4plot, Center, Center, ImageScaled[1]], 
 Epilog -> {Text[Style["x", FontSize -> 20], 
    ImageScaled[{0.03, .33}]], 
   Text[Style["y", FontSize -> 20], ImageScaled[{.97, .33}]], 
   Text[Style["z", FontSize -> 20], ImageScaled[{.5, .99}]]}]
BarLegend[{"DarkRainbow", {MinValue[
    hcpii4angfunc[θ, ϕ], {θ, ϕ}], 
   MaxValue[hcpii4angfunc[θ, ϕ], {θ, ϕ}]}}, 
 LegendLayout -> "Row", LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 14]]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
fun1[fun2_] := Module[
  {hcpii4plot},
  hcpii4plot = SphericalPlot3D[
    1
    , {θ, 0, π}
    , {ϕ, 0, 2 π}
    , ColorFunction -> Function[
      {x, y, z, θ, ϕ, r}
      , ColorData["DarkRainbow"][fun2[θ, ϕ]]]
    , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
    , Mesh -> False
    , Boxed -> False
    , AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}
    , PlotRange -> {{-1.3, 1.3}, {-1.3, 1.3}, {-1.22, 1.22}}
    , LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 14]
    , Ticks -> None
    , AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{-0.05, 0.05}]
    , Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}
    , ViewPoint -> {-2, -2, 1}
    , ViewVertical -> {1, 1, 1}
    ];
  Column@{
    Graphics[
     Inset[hcpii4plot, Center, Center, ImageScaled[1]]
     , Epilog -> {
       Text[Style["x", FontSize -> 20], ImageScaled[{0.03, .33}]],
       Text[Style["y", FontSize -> 20], ImageScaled[{.97, .33}]],
       Text[Style["z", FontSize -> 20], ImageScaled[{.5, .99}]]}
     ],
    BarLegend[{
      "DarkRainbow"
      , {MinValue[fun2[θ, ϕ], {θ, ϕ}]
       , MaxValue[fun2[θ, ϕ], {θ, ϕ}]}
      }
     , LegendLayout -> "Row"
     , LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 14]
     ]
    }
  ]
```

and then

```
fun1[hcpii4angfunc]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, yes this is what I was after! :-) Do you know why the image of the sphere is now smaller, or how to make it bigger? Is it possible to have a function to generate 2 lines of output, just like `hcpii4plot` ? Could you explain a bit how this Module and Column syntax works? But these are just curiosities, thank you for answering my main question!

Comment: Because it's in automatic size inside a `Column`. Try specifying a specific size such as `ImageSize-> 600`